# html width causing scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I have a basic webpage, but the html or body elements are too wide and they make a scrollbar pop up at the bottom. The width of the html/body tag stay at 980px. This happens in the Chrome dev tool. Pick the responsive resizer. The html/body wont resize below 980px. Im concerned small devices will get the scroll bar.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .con { 
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;    
        width:95%; justify-content: space-around;   
      }
            
      html { width: auto; }
      #one {
        background-color: white; 
        width:600px; height: auto;
      }
      #two { 
        background-color: #aaa;
        width: 500px; height:300px;
      }
      img { width:100%; }

      @media (max-width: 1099px) {
        .con {
          flex-direction: column;
        }
        #one, #two { width:95%; margin: 0 auto; }                
      }
    </style>
    
  </head>
    
  <body>
    <div class="con">
      <div id="one"><img src="images/backwide.jpg"></div>
      <div id="two"><h1>Hello world</h1></div>
    </div>
  </body>  
</html>
```

I tried setting the width of the html, I tried setting the width of the body too, but nothing worked. I am trying to keep the page neat. I understand that these elements are too wide, but they are unresponsive. This happens in Chrome's F12 responsize resizer tool.

Comment: the code you shared doesn't replicate your problem. Maybe because the image is missing. What are the dimensions of the image ?

Comment: Also, what's the screen resolution you are using?

Comment: See the below updated answer.

Comment: @MihaiT Even when there are no elements on the page, the width of the html/body are 980. It causes a scrollbar when I shrink the page to anything below that.

Comment: well it seems like we cannot replicate your problem. the snippet is working fine

Comment: @MihaiT When I hit F12 and use Chrome's responsive resizer, thats when it happens. Im concerned the page will do this on other devices. Try resizing below 980px. Then elements resize, but anything below 980 creates the scrollbar that I cant remove. Then all the other elements base their size off the html/body size. So everything is just a bit off screen. This happens in Chrome's F12 responsize resizer tool.

Comment: i tried replicating your problem, but i cannot : https://jsfiddle.net/8f5chmuk/3/

Comment: @MihaiT thank you for helping. Inside jsfiddle, open Chrome dev tools. Use the responsive resize. Resize the width window to 440px. Then the scrollbar appears. Thats the problem im having, but at 980 on my page (only when im inside the responsive resizer). Im concerned this will show on small devices. If you're not in the dev tool, it doesnt happen.

Comment: @MihaiT Please try that. This didnt happen in other sites I looked at. Is this something I should worry about or am I just noobing?

Comment: inside the jsfiddle, under 450 px the scrollbar appear because of the title. But under 450px in jsfiddle dev tools is under 100px in ' real life '. So that's unimportant. You could check in dev tools if any element exceeds the width of your screen. Like a text or the header for eg. Normally, with the code provided, you shouldn't have any problems

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit like that.

```
#one {
      background-color: white;
      max-width: 600px;
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      float: left;
    }

    #two {
      background-color: #aaa;
      max-width: 500px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 300px;
      float: left;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the simple method is to use max-width outside of the html elements so they will not make any scroll.I have added the wraper for all the body elements.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .con { 
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;    
        width:95%; justify-content: space-around;   
      }
      
      .my-wraper{max-width:100%; width:100%; height:auto;}
            
      html { width: auto; }
      #one {
        background-color: white; 
        width:600px; height: auto;
      }
      #two { 
        background-color: #aaa;
        width: 500px; height:300px;
      }
      img { width:100%; }

      @media (max-width: 1099px) {
        .con {
          flex-direction: column;
        }
        #one, #two { width:95%; margin: 0 auto; }                
      }
    </style>
    
  </head>
    
  <body>
  <div class="my-wraper">
    <div class="con">
      <div id="one"><img src="images/backwide.jpg"/></div>
      <div id="two"><h1>Hello world</h1></div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>  
</html>
```